# How to test if an input value = char A - Z in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, while-loop

```
 while (asteriskWord != hangCharacters && score < 5)
 {               
      while ( letter != ) //This is where I want to test for A-Z a-z
      { 
          Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter please");
          letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
      }
 }
```

After the first `while-loop` I want to be able to place the input inside of a while loop that breaks if the value is = letters **A-Z or a-z**.

This is so that if the user enters the wrong information, the loop will `continue` to ask for the information.

Thank you for your time and consideration. Also I tried doing letter != 'A' && letter != 'a'...... and so on, but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: what type of `letter`?

Comment: `if (!char.IsLetter(letter)) { ... }` See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Grundy: the same type as the result of `Convert.ToChar` ...

Comment: @RonBeyer That tests if it is a unicode letter, not if it's an ASCII letter.

Answer (score 13):

Characters can be compared to each other, just like numbers:

```
while (!((letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z') || (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z'))) {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter please");
    letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Well the simplest way would be to just use comparisons. If you definitely want to do it in a single expression, Glorfindel's answer is appropriate. However, all those brackets and the negation makes me nervous of the readability. I'd break it into a separate method:

```
while (!IsValidLetter(letter))
{
    ...
}

...

private static bool IsValidLetter(char letter)
{
    return (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') ||
           (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z');
}
```

Whichever you find more readable - the latter is easier to modify later, of course, if you end up with more complicated requirements.

Comment: Jon, can you explain why you feel this is better than the `char.IsLetter`? I'm not sure I understand what the drawbacks of the built-in method is. Thanks.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Well `char.IsLetter` doesn't meet the requirements. It includes things like [U+01C5](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01c5/index.htm)

Comment: @RonBeyer: `IsLetter` will return `true` for any *unicode* letter, which includes much more than A-Za-z. Check the "remarks" section in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks guys, missed that part.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a regular expression, like this:

```
        while (!Regex.IsMatch(letter, "[a-zA-Z]"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter please!");
            letter = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```